# How to find averages from a table that has common variables

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that contains dates and wind speeds. However, there are multiple wind speeds for each date and I'm wondering how I can average the wind speeds for each date? The table is very long and doing it by hand would be inefficient. Here is the table and what it should look like in the end (I did part of it by hand):

[image]

Table with averages for each date:

[image]

Comment: I believe you are looking for [`AVERAGEIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-FAEC8E2E-0DEC-4308-AF69-F5576D8AC642)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why [pivot tables](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) exist in Excel.

1. Select your data
2. Go to insert - pivot table
3. Add date to "rows"
4. Add wind speed to values and set aggregation to average

Answer (score 2):

Two step process

#### Step 1 - Generate a list of Unique Dates

You need to generate a list of unique dates or in other words remove duplicates.  There are plenty of ways to do this and a quick google search should turn up a variety of methods.  There is also a built in method in your ribbon, in the data tab in the data tools sections.

[image: Remove Duplicates]

Generate your list of unique values in column D starting in D2.

#### Step 2 - Find your average for a specified date

In this case AVERAGEIF will be your friend but may be version dependent.  Not sure which version it came out in.  Place the following in E2 and copy down as required

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,D2,B:B)
```

It will look through all of column A and only select the the rows where they are equal D2 and then use the value sitting in column B for determining the average.

NOTE if you have data in column A below your table that could accidently match then change the full column A reference A:A to just the rows you want to look at A2:A22.  Limit the rows for B in the same fashion if required.